# Calculting logLikelihood and AICs "by hand"

Tags: logistic, aic

I'm a total newbee, when it comes to R and I need some help - my task is to calculate the logLikelihood and the AIC for a logistic regression, without using the logLik() fuction or the AIC() function.
This is what I have so far :

```
#Model:
mod<-glm(Krebs~Radius+Dichte+Homogenitaet, family=binomial)
summary(mod)
# Loglikelihood :
lambdas<-exp(mod$coefficients[1]+mod$coefficients[2]*Radius+mod$coefficients[3]
             *Dichte+mod$coefficients[3]*Homogenitaet)/
  (1+exp(mod$coefficients[1]+mod$coefficients[2]*Radius+mod$coefficients[3]
        *Dichte+mod$coefficients[3]*Homogenitaet))

logLikelihood<-sum(log(dbinom(Krebs,lambdas, p= )))
logLikelihood

##AIC:
-2*logLikelihood+2*4
```

My biggest problem right now is that i have no idea how to calculate p. I'm aware that p is the probability of the model. However I just can't think of a function right know, how to calculate it.
BTW : The Variable "Krebs" is a dummy variable.

I would really appreciate some help and I'm really sorry for my english. :)